# Constructing Szemerédi partitions on a computer

Tags: graph-theory

Are there *practical* ways to construct the [Szemerédi partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma) of a given graph (on a computer)?  I found [this algorithmic version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_version_for_Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_partition) of the lemma (also see the references within), but I was unable to find any implementations, so I am wondering if these algorithms are practical at all.

Please note that I am not a mathematician and I am very new to this topic.  I am trying to find out if it this will be useful for me.  I was hoping that someone familiar with the field will be able to provide some guidance and help avoid a likely blind alley.

Also, can partitioning the graph like this recursively be used to define/compute a vertex ordering (ordering = labelling by natural numbers), so that the vertices in the same partition will be adjacent in the ordering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of this information is apparently available through links from Wikipedia, so my apologies if this is not helpful (or useful enough to warrant being an answer).

I highly doubt this can be done in a practical way. The algorithm of Frieze and Kannan requires $O\left(\varepsilon^{-45}\right)$ steps, most of which require a nontrivial amount of work (specifically, step 4 requires $O(n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of vertices in your graph.

I think a larger problem is the size of the graphs required to apply the regularity lemma. [This paper by Gowers](http://www.springerlink.com/content/xndpevxb8p10awxb/) shows a lower bound on M similar to a tower of 2's of height $\log\left(\varepsilon^{-5}\right)$. Since, say, a tower of five 2's is far larger than the number of bits available to a computer for memory, there will be considerable trouble representing a graph with this many vertices in the first place.

Comment: @Calvin Condon, thank you for the pointer.   I am not a mathematician, and very new to this topic, but the abstract of this paper gave me the impression that this partitioning should work for any graph, and should be implementable in practice: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.102.681

Comment: But then apparently one needs a graph of a minimum size for a given $\epsilon$.

Comment: The link to the paper by Gowers at `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: The link to CiteSeerX in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70987/constructing-szemer%c3%a9di-partitions-on-a-computer/70989#comment180089_70989) above is broken; it is supposed to link to the following paper: _Alon, N.; Duke, Richard A.; Lefmann, Hanno; Rödl, Vojtěch; Yuster, R._, [**The algorithmic aspects of the regularity lemma**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1994.1005), J. Algorithms 16, No. 1, 80–109 (1994). [Zbl 0794.05119](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0794.05119).